# Length and capacity methods in slices

Tags: go

[Reading](http://blog.golang.org/slices) about arrays and slices in Golang.

Why built-in functions like `len` and `cap` are used and not similar methods on slice objects?

```
if cap(slice) == len(slice) {
    fmt.Println("slice is full!")
}
```

vs

```
if slice.cap() == slice.len() {
    fmt.Println("slice is full!")
}
```

Why polluting the global namespace? Why not using object oriented style?

Also, do such methods exist and can they be used instead of built-in functions?

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_basics

Answer (score 2):

There is a [FAQ entry on this](http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_basics), but here is my take:

`len()` and `cap()` are built in functions because they are understood by the compiler. You can't make your own replacements - they are very much part of the core language in a way that methods aren't, and you shouldn't confuse them with methods.

In Go a slice is made of three things, a [length, a capacity and a pointer to the underlying memory](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader). Eg the definition from `reflect`

```
type SliceHeader struct {
        Data uintptr
        Len  int
        Cap  int
}
```

All `len(x)` does is read the length from the slice structure, so it is shorthand for something like `x.Len` and the compiler understands that and optimises it accordingly.